# Invalid procedure call or argument error when worksheet_change procedure is called

Tags: excel, vba

I have this procedure in some worksheets of my workbook:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address <> "$W$1" Then
    Cells(1, 23).Value2 = True
End If
End Sub
```

When some change is made to one of the sheets, the error occurs.
I tried compiling and excel points me to the following function in a module alerting the same error:

```
Public Function getProdsWb() As Workbook
Dim prodsWBName As String
prodsWBName = "Produtos e suas data de adição.xlsx"
openWBInCurrentDirectoryOrInFoldersInsideIt prodsWBName
Set getProdsWb = Workbooks(prodsWBName)
End Function
```

It was all working fine until yesterday.
I tried searching for a solution but i couldn't find something that seemed to relate to my problem.

Comment: Can you explain what these procedures are trying to achieve? It seems a bit non-sensical to me that the worksheet change event would change the value of cell W1 for each and every change in the worksheet, and then call itself.

Comment: It doesn't call itself every time, it calls itself just if the change is to a cell other than cell W1. I am doing this cause I want to keep track if some change has been made to the worksheet after the value of W1 is set to false by another procedure.

Comment: @FaneDuru, no, i think there are no other events used, the worksheets contain only that procedure in their code "behind" them, I also didn't set up Workbook_open. Apart from this procedure in each of some worksheets, there's only a CommandButton1_Click in another worksheet. The cell "w1" is not targeted by formulas, it is read by a procedure in another workbook. I need opening a workbook in the procedure that is triggered by the click of the button. The sub openWBInCurrentDirectoryOrInFoldersInsideIt takes care of inserting that full name you talked about. Thanks for replying.

Comment: It **DOES** trigger itself. The fact that it only continues to run if the cell is **NOT** W1 is in there **BECAUSE** it triggers itself, no? Just step through it and see. You should use `Application.EnableEvents=FALSE` at the beginning and set it to `TRUE` before the end of the routine.. THEN it will not trigger itself.